# Compute costs only of paths between all pairs in weighted graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Is there an algorithm faster than O(n2) for computing the costs **only** between every pair in a weighted non-cyclic graph, assuming I do not need the shortest paths but just the paths I would get if using simple BFS? I do not need the actual paths, only the costs of the paths. My current solution is just to do a BFS starting from each node also keeping track of the weights of the edges along the way but this is obviously O(n2) and I am wondering if it is possible to do any better.

Comment: Does your graph representation store the edges as an explicit iterable? Also, there can be multiple paths between any two nodes, so which cost are you looking for?

Comment: I am currently using adjacency lists, but this is not a requirement.

Comment: I am looking for the cost of whatever path would be followed using a basic BFS search ignoring the weights of the edges.

Comment: Well, icepack has given the trivial lower bound that answers the question as written. Is there more context that you could add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no algorithm better then O(n<sup>2</sup>).
The algorithm will need to at least go over each pair. There are O(n<sup>2</sup>) possible pairs in the graph:
[image]. Therefore the algorithm bottom boundary is [image] = O(n<sup>2</sup>).